# Problems with ls -l | grep combination

Tags: linux, bash

i want to see all files that end with .sh through a ls -l | grep combination. The problem with that is that it has to show only the filename, no other attributes. How do I do this with a ls-l | grep combination?

Comment: Have you tried anything? The internet is filled with easy grep tutorials that cover these as their first basics.

Comment: `ls -l` by definition shows more than the filename.  And why do you need grep? Try just `ls *.sh`

Comment: Only one filename per line with ls and without grep: `ls -1 *.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in two ways, one with grep and one without grep:

1. `ls -a | grep "\.sh"`

or

2. `ls *.sh`